# sbt assembly for multiproject build

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a multiproject sbt build file like this

```
import sbt._                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
import Keys._                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

object TestBuild extends Build {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  lazy val root = Project(id = "test",                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    base = file(".")) aggregate(core, handlers)                                                                                                                                                                                        

  lazy val core = Project(id = "test-core",                                                                                                                                                                                            
    base = file("core"))                                                                                                                                                                                                               

  lazy val handlers = Project(id = "test-handlers",                                                                                                                                                                                    
    base = file("handlers")) dependsOn (core)                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

How can I build an assembly-jar that includes all the dependencies + core + handlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved this problem using

```
import sbt._                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
import Keys._                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

object TestBuild extends Build {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  lazy val root = Project(id = "test",                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    base = file(".")) aggregate(core, handlers) dependsOn(core,handlers)                                                                                                                                                                                        

  lazy val core = Project(id = "test-core",                                                                                                                                                                                            
    base = file("core"))                                                                                                                                                                                                               

  lazy val handlers = Project(id = "test-handlers",                                                                                                                                                                                    
    base = file("handlers")) dependsOn (core)                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

I put the assembly settings in the build.sbt file

Comment: Is that a build.sbt or a .scala file?

Comment: @MatthewAdams its a .scala file

Answer (score 0):

You can use sbt-assembly plugin.

`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.7.3")`

Comment: I am using sbt-assembly already. What Im not sure is how I can use it in a multiproject build.